# ReactJS: HTML5 Canvas render error in iOS device (>= iPhone 8)

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, canvas, countdowntimer

I try to create a countdown clock using canvas and useEffect. It work fine until I test it in iPhone's browser (all device >= iPhone 8). When my clock running on iPhone 8, sometimes it has issue look like in picture.

This issue don't happend in other device (android, laptop, iphone <= 6)
Please help me!
[image]
[![`

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('percent canvas = ', percent);
    // var canvas = document.getElementById("clockCanvas");
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, width);
    ctx.lineWidth = strokeWidth;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = backgroundClock;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.strokeStyle = colorStroke;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, -0.5 * Math.PI + (2 * (percent / 100) * Math.PI), - 0.5 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = textStrokeWidth;
    ctx.strokeStyle = textStrokeColor;
    ctx.font = `${textSize}px Roboto`;
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.strokeText(text, width / 2, width / 2, width - 2 * strokeWidth);
    ctx.closePath();

  }, 
  [
    cx,
    cy,
    radius,
    width,
    percent,
    strokeColor,
    strokeWidth,
    text,
    textSize,
    textStrokeColor,
    textStrokeWidth
  ]);

  return (
    <canvas id="clockCanvas" width={width} height={width} ref={canvasRef}>
      
    </canvas>
  );
};

export default Clock;
```

`][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ejyf.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ejyf.png)

Answer (score 1):

Hey there Do Anh Bon!

I know this question is 8 months old, so I'm assuming that you found a solution, but in case you did not...

I am working on a web development project and encountered a similar error. I spent quite some time doing research on the topic and I believed that I had tried nearly everything (changing image rendering settings in CSS, messing with device pixel ratio in various ways, etc.). None of the suggestions even came close to fixing the problem. Some of them actually made the code more verbose and the resulting image less appealing on top of that.

What I *finally* found to be the solution was to simply **use the close path function INSTEAD of drawing the last iteration (meaning the last line) of my drawing**. What this does is simply connect the line to the starting position.

```
function drawShape(x, y, radius, inset, n) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(" + hue + ",100%,50%)";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.save();
  

  ctx.translate(x, y)
  ctx.moveTo(0, -radius);

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / n);
    ctx.lineTo(0, -radius * inset);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / n);
    if (i === n - 1) {
      break;
    } else {
      ctx.lineTo(0, -radius);
    }
  }

  ctx.restore();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
}
```

Keep in mind that since you are attempting to draw a curved line, this solution may not work for you (I have not tried it out with your code).

If this solution does not work, then another thing you might want to try to to **omit the use of close path and see what results you get then**.

I really hope this helps!

-Keith

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ilOF.jpg)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMdyF.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have found another solution (just a trick). I used `z-index` and `overflow: hidden ` to hide blurred part.

Comment: This issue is a bug of webkit on iOS 12 (or 13, I don't remember) and this bug was reported by someone for Apple developers, I lost the link report this bug. If I find out it, I will send you.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I would love to see it!